Can three given coordinates be points of a rectangle
I am currently learning how to code in Python and I came across this task and I am trying to solve it. But I think I got a mistake somewhere and I was wondering can maybe someone help me with it. The task is to write a code that will:
Import four  2D coordinates (A, B, C and X) from a text file
Check can A, B, C be points of a rectangle
Check if X is inside the ABC rectangle
Calculate the diagonal of the rectangle.
So far I have this:
import math

def distance(point1, point2):
    return math.sqrt((point2[0] - point1[0])**2 + (point2[1] - point1[1])**2)

def is_rectangle(point1, point2, point3):
    distances = [
        distance(point1, point2),
        distance(point2, point3),
        distance(point3, point1)
    ]

    distances.sort()

    if distances[0] == distances[1] and distances[1] != distances[2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def is_inside_rectangle(rectangle, point):
    x_values = [vertex[0] for vertex in rectangle]
    y_values = [vertex[1] for vertex in rectangle]

    if (min(x_values) < point[0] < max(x_values)) and (min(y_values) < point[1] < max(y_values)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

with open('coordinates.txt', 'r') as file:
    coordinates = []
    for line in file:
        x, y = map(int, line.strip()[1:-1].split(','))
        coordinates.append((x, y))

rectangle = [coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2]]
diagonal1 = distance(coordinates[0], coordinates[2])
diagonal2 = distance(coordinates[1], coordinates[3])
if is_rectangle(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2]) and is_inside_rectangle(rectangle, coordinates[3]):
    print("True")
    print(f"Diagonal of the rectangle is: {max(diagonal1, diagonal2)}")

else:
    print("False")


The code works but I think it calculates the diagonal wrong. For example lets take this points for input: A(0, 0), B(5,0), C(0, 5) and X(2, 2). It says they can be points of a rectangle and that the diagonal is 5. When I put this points on paper, the fourth point can be D(5, 5) and then the diagonal is 7.07 (square root of 50). Or it can be D(-5, 5) but then it is a parallelogram and one diagonal is 5 but it is not the max one.
Also I am trying to write a function that will check if all data in the text file are integers. Let's say B is (m, k), then it should return false and if all data are integers, then continue with the code. Any ideas on that one?

You are asking too many questions in one go. They can be part of a rectangle if, for two pairs of points, their joining lines are at 90 degrees. The diagonal is the length of the line joining the non-common point. For whether X is inside you can rotate to alignment with the coordinate axes and simply check the bounds. (Alternatively, there’s an area-based argument that works with general polygons.) In your example the diagonal should indeed be 5.sqrt(2). Integers is another question entirely, and I’ve run out of space.

Hi. Could you please clarify what you mean by "point of a rectangle"? Does the sentence "A is a point of rectangle (R)" mean (1) A is one of the four vertices of (R); (2) A is on one of the sides of (R); (3) A is inside rectangle (R)?

Hi @Stef, it is (1) A is one of the four vertices of the rectangle.

"The code works" - No it doesn't. For example is_rectangle((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 2)) returns False.

Note that there isn't just one rectangle. As long as three points A, B, and C aren't colinear, there can be an infinite number of rectangles that those points lie on, with the "trivial" rectangle having the two points that are furthest apart as two vertices with an edge E between them, two sides that are parallel to the projection vector P of the third point onto E, and a final edge parallel to E passing through your third point.

Let's look at the logic for your is_rectangle function.
def is_rectangle(point1, point2, point3):
    distances = [
        distance(point1, point2),
        distance(point2, point3),
        distance(point3, point1)
    ]

    distances.sort()

    if distances[0] == distances[1] and distances[1] != distances[2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

You are testing if the two smallest sides of triangle ABC are equal, and different from the largest side.
Effectively answering the question: "Is ABC an obtuse isosceles triangle?"
But the question you should be asking is: "Is ABC a right triangle?"
There are several ways to test whether a triangle ABC is a right triangle.

One way is to check if one of the three pairs of vectors (AB,AC), (BA,BC), (CA, CB) is orthogonal, ie if its dot product is 0.
Another way is to check if the three distances AB, AC, BC form a Pythagorean triplet, ie if z**2 == x**2 + y**2 is true when x,y,z = sorted(map(distance,itertools.combinations(points,2)))

PS: In general when you write if condition: return True else: return False, you might as well write directly return condition.
With that in mind, the code you wrote in python for this function is equivalent to:
from itertools import combinations

def is_acute_isosceles_triangle(point1, point2, point3):
    distances = sorted(map(distance, combinations((point1,point2,point3), 2)))
    return (distances[0] == distances[1] and distances[1] != distances[2])


Thanks man, your advice worked!

In addition to @Stef's answer, you could simplify the logic by using slopes :
def find_fourth(*points): # 3
    from itertools import combinations
    zs = next(
        (
            comb
            for comb in combinations(points, 2)
            if comb[0][1] == comb[1][1]
        ),
        None,
    )

    if zs and (diff := {*points}.difference(zs)):
        x, y = diff.pop()
        m = abs(zs[0][0] - zs[1][0])
        return (x + m, y), (x - m, y)

Output :
A = (0, 0)
B = (5, 0)
C = (0, 5)

find_fourth(A, B, C) # ((5, 5), (-5, 5))

Desmos :

